# Oracle xml sql in case of 2 groups

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

Table has 4 columns a, b, c, d where a has group of records and each has group of b records and each of b has c and d values.
How can I produce the result below using Oracle xml sql? All examples relates to emp table with only 1 grouping on "employee". What if one more grouping needed for example "city"?
Thanks.

```
<GROUP_A>
   <a val="1">
      <Group_B>
         <b val="1">
            <Group_C>
               <C>
                  <c>1</c>
                  <d>1</d>
               </C>
               <C>
                  <c>2</c>
                  <d>2</d>
               </C>
            </Group_C>
         </b>
         <b val="2">
            <Group_C>
               <C>
                  <c>1</c>
                  <d>1</d>
               </C>
               <C>
                  <c>2</c>
                  <d>2</d>
               </C>
            </Group_C>
         </b>
      </Group_B>
   </a>
   <a val="2">
      <Group_B>
         <b val="1">
            <Group_C>
               <C>
                  <c>1</c>
                  <d>1</d>
               </C>
               <C>
                  <c>2</c>
                  <d>2</d>
               </C>
            </Group_C>
         </b>
         <b val="2">
            <Group_C>
               <C>
                  <c>1</c>
                  <d>1</d>
               </C>
               <C>
                  <c>2</c>
                  <d>2</d>
               </C>
            </Group_C>
         </b>
      </Group_B>
   </a>
</GROUP_A>
```

OP tried this

```
SELECT XMLElement("Group_A", XMLAttributes(a AS "a"), 
       Xmlagg( XMLELEMENT ("Group_b", XMLAttributes(b AS "b"), 
       XMLELEMENT ("c",c), XMLELEMENT ("d",c) ) ) ) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY a
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: I tried this: SELECT XMLElement("Group_A", 
        XMLAttributes(a AS "a"),
        Xmlagg(  XMLELEMENT ("Group_b",
              XMLAttributes(b AS "b"),
                 XMLELEMENT ("c",c),
                 XMLELEMENT ("d",c)
                    )               
                 )
          )
FROM table
GROUP BY a

Answer (score 0):

Here's a query that will return what you want :

```
SELECT 
XMLELEMENT(
         "Group_A",
         XMLAGG(
           XMLELEMENT(
             "a", 
             XMLATTRIBUTES(A AS "val"),
             (SELECT   
               XMLELEMENT (
                 "Group_b", 
                 XMLAGG( 
                   XMLELEMENT(
                     "b", 
                     XMLATTRIBUTES(t1.B AS "val"),
                     XMLELEMENT (
                       "Group_C", 
                       XMLAGG(
                         XMLELEMENT (
                           "C",
                           XMLELEMENT ("c",T1.C), 
                           XMLELEMENT ("d",t1.D)
                         )
                       )
                     )
                   )
                 )
               )
             FROM TEST T1
             WHERE T1.A = T2.A
             GROUP BY t1.A, t1.B)
           )
         )
       )

FROM (SELECT distinct t3.a FROM TEST t3) T2;
```

Comment: @user3358291 great, I tested it before I post it ;) so please consider accepting the answer :)

Comment: Sure, how can I do it? It's my first time using this system.